# how to create an array of char arrays in arduino

Tags: arrays, pointers, matrix, arduino, char

I need to handle data in a matrix. I want to have something like this:

```
{{"data11", "data12", "data13"},
{"data21", "data22", "data23"},
{"data31", "data32", "data33"}}
```

I think that "`char* matrix[3][3];`" could do the trick, but I haven't gotten the expected result.

I need to do the following actions:

1. Initialize the matrix empty (with empty Strings or something like `""`).
2. Put data in the matrix dynamically.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should use character arrays, not pointers to string to modify its contents later.

```
#include <string.h>

// this will be initialized to "" because this is global variable
// Please allocate enough memory for each elements
// (adjust last number [10]if needed)
char matrix[3][3][10];

void setup() {
  // put data in the matrix
  strcpy(matrix[0][0], "data11");
  strcpy(matrix[0][1], "data12");
  strcpy(matrix[0][2], "data13");
  strcpy(matrix[1][0], "data21");
  strcpy(matrix[1][1], "data22");
  strcpy(matrix[1][2], "data23");
  strcpy(matrix[1][0], "data31");
  strcpy(matrix[1][1], "data32");
  strcpy(matrix[1][2], "data33");
}

void loop() {
}
```

Or do you want to use `String`?

```
// this will be initialized to "" because this is global variable
String matrix[3][3];

void setup() {
  // put data in the matrix
  matrix[0][0] = "data11";
  matrix[0][1] = "data12";
  matrix[0][2] = "data13";
  matrix[1][0] = "data21";
  matrix[1][1] = "data22";
  matrix[1][2] = "data23";
  matrix[2][0] = "data31";
  matrix[2][1] = "data32";
  matrix[2][2] = "data33";
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: the type of the data that I must handle is `char *`. Using the `String()` function I can cast the `char *` to `String`, so your second alternative worked just fine for me. Thank you.